# Don't overwrite existing Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

For a given Notification ID is it possible (using standard android packages) not to set a notification if there is an existing notification from the app ?

I have a news application notifying users on breaking news headlines, one of the requirement is not to over write a breaking news if the user has not cleared it or has not clicked to view it.

Im using a SharedPreference to set a flag to figure out if Im already showing a headline plus a delete intent that'll clear it. However the deleteIntent isn't always invoked when the user clears all notification.

Thanks in advance.

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following this later:

There's no easy way to **not** to overwrite a existing Notification ID using the SDK. The way to do this is:

- use a boolean flag via SharedPreference, if this flag is set then don't write the notification
- reset this flag when the user "Clear"s all notification. To do this setup a deleteIntent (via a Service), make sure you clear this flag in  the onStartCommand() and onStart()
- optionally reset the flag when the app is launched

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is :

> one of the requirement is not to over write a breaking news if the user has not cleared it or has not clicked to view it.

You can use [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) for getting list of all the active notifications posted by your application using [`getActiveNotifications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications())

And check if the user has dismissed or opened the notification and take the required action.

As per the reference doc for `getActiveNotifications()`:

> Recover a list of active notifications: ones that have been posted by the calling app that have not yet been dismissed by the user or cancelled by the app.

Hope it helps.